# Make MiddleMouse in Vim switch to insert (paste), paste, and then escape

Tags: vim, paste

I am using a Windows machine connected to `CentOS 7` through `MobaXterm`. I want the middle mouse button to work in `Vim 7.4` (compiled without the clipboard option) as it does on the linux command line, which is to paste from my Windows clipboard.

In my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr>:startinsert<MiddleMouse><esc>
```

At first, I worried that this might not do what I expect because maybe I don't understand how Vim does recursion, so I tried it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, since that is what MiddleMouse maps to in order to paste:

```
nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr>:startinsert<S-Insert><esc>
```

This gives an error about `E488: Trailing characters`.

**Edit**: as Christian pointed out, I was missing a `<cr>` after the `:startinsert` command, but that still did not solve my issue.

```
nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr>:startinsert<cr><S-Insert><esc>
```

will no longer have an error, but it doesn't enter `insert` mode before I paste.

Comment: are you missing a `<cr>`?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons.... >.< Yes. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, could you explain why `nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr>:startinsert<cr><S-Insert><esc>` does not return me to normal mode like I would expect the last `<esc>` to do?

Comment: Is the issue that you're still in paste mode?

Comment: After reading `:help startinsert` it looks like the issue is that `:startinsert` is executed last, regardless of its order in the command. So my command turns on paste, pastes from the clipboard (and will eventually switch to insert when it reaches a `a` or `i` character), escapes insert mode, and then `:startinsert` happens and puts me back to `insert`. I'm assuming I'll need to make a function to fix this?

Comment: If you're just trying to paste from the clipboard, what about something like this: `:set nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr>"+p:set nopaste<cr>`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, that has the same problem, where I'm not in insert mode so characters before `a` or `i` are truncated / cause me to move around the file.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Unless I am misunderstanding your problem `"+p` does not work that way.  It works like `p` does, except it uses the clipboard rather than the unnamed buffer.  The linux middle-click, on the other hand, is more like inputting a series of keystrokes into vim that are equivalent to what's in the middle-click buffer (which is why that middle-click trick works even without clipboard support in vim)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons yes. `nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr>"+p:set nopaste<cr>` in my `~/.vimrc` directly types the words in normal mode, rather than pasting everything in the clipboard to that line, and `:set nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr>"+p:set nopaste<cr>` gave `Unknown option: nnoremap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently expected behavior (ugh).

```
:star[tinsert][!]   Start Insert mode just after executing this command.
                    Works like typing "i" in Normal mode.  When the ! is
                    included it works like "A", append to the line.
                    Otherwise insertion starts at the cursor position.
                    Note that when using this command in a function or
                    script, the insertion only starts after the function
                    or script is finished.
                    This command does not work from :normal.
```

What this means is that all of my commands that I put after `:startinsert` instead run immediately before `:startinsert` and then `:startinsert` runs and changes the mode to insert (Note: this appears to hold true for using `i` instead of `:startinsert` as well).

My next step was to try to make a nested function, where I had one function that calls another function, and the second function runs `:startinsert` and then returns to the first function, which then completes the paste:

```
function! Paste()
  call InsertMode()<cr>
  :set paste<cr>
  <S-Insert>
  :set nopaste<cr>
  <esc>
endfunction
function! InsertMode()
  :startinsert<cr>
endfunction
nnoremap <MiddleMouse> call Paste()<cr>
```

But this did not work either. I also tried using the `"+p` and `"*p` registers without `:startinsert` as Christian said in his comments with `nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr>"+p:set nopaste<cr>`, but this again just pastes directly as if I were typing it in, it does not enter `insert` mode first. I am willing to believe this would work on a version of Vim compiled with +clipboard, but that is not the version I have.

The best I have been able to do is to paste correctly with the MiddleMouse button after already entering `insert` mode:

```
inoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr><S-Insert>:set nopaste<cr>
```

If anyone knows of a way to do this from `normal` mode, please let me know. It seems like it should be possible, but everything I've read suggests that without the `+clipboard` option (checkable with `vim --version | grep clipboard`) it is not.