# Enter insert mode between two tags after command in vim

Tags: vim

I'm looking to change the following vim command so that after entering the :%s/temp123//g part it will put me into insert mode between the \begin and \end tags.

```
 inoremap \\beg \begin{temp123}<enter><enter>\end{temp123}<enter><esc>:%s/temp123//g<left><left>
```

I have been able to use :startinsert to get into go into insert mode after entering the search/replace command but I am not able to place the cursor between the \begin and \end tags.

Any help/solutions/improvements would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I am now using.

```
function TexBegin()
    let currline = line(".")
    call inputsave()
    let tagname = input("enter tag name: ")
    call inputrestore()                            
    call setline(currline, "\\begin{" . tagname . "    }")
    normal o
    normal o
    call setline(currline + 2, "\\end{" . tagname .     "}")
    normal l
    startinsert
    normal o<Esc>
endfunction 
inoremap  \\beg <Esc>:call TexBegin()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: can't.

> ```
> :star[tinsert][!]   Start Insert mode just after executing this command.
>                     Works like typing "i" in Normal mode.  When the ! is
>                     included it works like "A", append to the line.
>                     Otherwise insertion starts at the cursor position.
>                     Note that when using this command in a function or
>                     script, the insertion only starts after the function
>                     or script is finished.
>                     This command does not work from :normal.
> ```

I was trying to get the following line working:

```
nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr>:startinsert<MiddleMouse><esc>
```

What this means is that all of my commands that I put after `:startinsert` instead run immediately before `:startinsert` and then `:startinsert` runs and changes the mode to insert (Note: this appears to hold true for using `i` instead of `:startinsert` as well).

My next step was to try to make a nested function, where I had one function that calls another function, and the second function runs `:startinsert` and then returns to the first function, which then completes the paste:

```
function! Paste()
  call InsertMode()<cr>
  :set paste<cr>
  <S-Insert>
  :set nopaste<cr>
  <esc>
endfunction
function! InsertMode()
  :startinsert<cr>
endfunction
nnoremap <MiddleMouse> call Paste()<cr>
```

But this did not work either. I also tried using the `"+p` and `"*p` registers without `:startinsert` with `nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :set paste<cr>"+p:set nopaste<cr>`, but this again just pastes directly as if I were typing it in, it does not enter `insert` mode first. I am willing to believe this would work on a version of Vim compiled with +clipboard, but that is not the version I have. [Link to my original question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49561616/make-middlemouse-in-vim-switch-to-insert-paste-paste-and-then-escape)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you're looking for an interactive substitution, but :s/new/old/g**c** doesn't let you edit each match. For this kind of work, switch to the <kbd>gn</kbd> command + <kbd>.</kbd> recipe:

First search for {temp123} (or whatever you wish to replace) with <kbd>/</kbd> 
Then press <kbd>cgn</kbd> to change the visually selected next match
Once done, go back to normal mode to commit your edits.
If the next edit is the same as the last, press only <kbd>.</kbd> otherwise <kbd>cgn</kbd> 
Rise and repeat.

For more ideas, see this vimcast: [gn command](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/)